# libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Tags: installation, apt, dependencies

after upgrading to the newest version I can't start up my pc. I receive the error:
The system is running in low-graphics mode

After looking into the forums, I go into the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + F1) I assumed this could be related to graphic drivers.

It seems I need to install libc6-i386, but the dependencies are broken:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm very noob. Not sure what details you would need.

Output of apt-cache policy libgcc1:i386
is

```
libgcc1:i386:
installed version: 1:4.7.3-1ubuntu1
candidate: 1:4.7.3-1ubuntu1
table of versions:
*** 1:4.7.3-1ubuntu1 0
500 http://sk.arcive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I tried the proposed solution on that thread and while following one of them I most likely removed a lot of paramount pieces of the OS. I do no longer receive the error The system is running in low-graphics mode. Now the pc goes into GNU GRUB right away and I am completely stuck. Any  idea on how to completely remove the remaining bits of ubuntu and reinstall from scratch?

Comment: I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS` and also have this problem. How is this problem a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

If `sudo apt-get -f install` removed lots of packages and still have internet connection you may want to install `ubuntu-desktop` again:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

That should make it.